monit website This site can’t be reached
I follow the tutorial to setup Monit on my vps which does not include support but I cannot reach the website for monit using public ip it work fine in localhost I followed this page in this website monit: can't connect to the http interface  but the issue still going then I used this page How To Install and Configure Monit but still not working my configuration is as following
set httpd port 2812 use
 use address 38.242.154.32  # only accept connection from localhost (drop if you use M/Monit)
 allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0        # allow localhost to connect to the server and
 allow user:password      # require user 'admin' with password 'monit'


Maybe comment out the use address ... line?  Then you access it in a browser are you using http://38.242.154.32:2812/?

@Zoredache yes but commenting out this want work

Check the monit.log, you should see the blocked incomming address. To allow your browser, add a proper "allow 12.34.56.0/24" line, with the address used by your browser (system).

allow 0.0.0.0

Allows local access to Monit, see https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#Host-and-network-allow-list
A suggestion only,
Lutz
p.s.
You should see some messages like the following in the monitor log.
[2024-06-20T16:22:38+0200] error    : Denied connection from non-authorized client [12.34.56.78]
[2024-06-20T16:22:38+0200] error    : Denied connection from non-authorized client [12.34.56.78]

